# Auditing my D7 Site after upgrade to 7.32 w/ Zen

Tags: security

As a security nut case, I should have taken the last Drupal Core security update seriously. I did not, as we're in the process of building a brand new version of the website, and were planning on launching it onto a brand new server within the next month or two.

Until today, when I read more about it, and said "oh, yikes!" to myself.

Note that I ***do not have evidence*** that the website or the server was compromised. Everything done below was completed as a precaution.

After realizing to my horror that my MySQL backups hadn't run in quite a long time and realizing that restoring from backkups was out of the question, I pulled fresh code for Drupal Core, all of the drupal modules, and Zen.

I then deployed to a brand new server (fresh install of CentOS 7), which incidentally was a nice upgrade from the older CentOS 6 I had been using), taking a copy of the database I made today.

Obviously, the code is freshly downloaded, but my Zen subtheme and the database remains.

Before dumping the MySQL database from the old server, I did a spot check in /admin/people (This is purely an anonymous user site except for the site admin - me), the list of the content (/admin/content), and the settings on our webforms.

I didn't look at each individual page, but out of this list of what I did do, nothing seemed out of the ordinary. I also reviewed bandwidth & CPU graphs for the server, and didn't see any out-of-the-ordinary spikes in traffic.

I also ran a scan of the site using http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/, ran a check on http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dqyWYp/developcents.com (and mentally compared it to previous scans I've run), and check blacklists using http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3adevelopcents.com&run=toolpage.

All come up clean.

Are there any additional measures I should take to either
a) ensure the website is "cleaned up" and
b) check for backdoors, malware, etc...?